# why I'm getting unicode errors here? Can anyone help me?

Tags: directory, package, data-science, visualization, data-analysis

[as I'm using chdir getting an unicode error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLG69.png)

best solution for this unable to change the working directory of the current path of the file and if this one-line code resolved then I do my visualization better and I learn the new concepts in my subject .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.